# Kendo-combobox valuePrimitive OnValueChange trigger

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-combobox

In kendo-combobox, the valuePrimitive property when set to true, the OnValueChange is triggered twice.

Kindly look at the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oZHExqJ65bYxkwQA300b?p=preview) for more info

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <kendo-combobox
        [data]="data"
        [textField]="'text'"
        [valueField]="'value'"
        (valueChange)="handleValue($event)"
        [valuePrimitive]="true"
    >
    </kendo-combobox>
    <br />

    Last 10 calls:
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let call of eventCalls">{{ call.name }}: <pre>{{ call.value | json }}</pre></li>
    </ul>
  `
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not reproducible with the latest version

```
handleValue(value) { 
  console.log('value change')
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JwdRmBSjxqyKG3AbWW5r?p=preview

Comment: It is producible in your plunkr version as well. After selecting the item, just click in some other part of the page.(eg just next to combobox).It triggers again.

Comment: I can see that you opened an issue in the GitHub repo, so it will be reviewed. Thanks!